# In Friends S1E7, what did Joey say in a low, twisted voice?

Tags: dialogue, friends

In *Friends* S1E7, "The one with the blackout", Chandler was locked in an ATM vestibule with Jill Goodacre. A conversation between him and Joey is as follows:

> Chandler: I am trapped in an ATM vestibule with Jill Goodacre.
>
> Joey: (something inaudible)
>
> Chandler: Like that never crossed my mind.

So I wonder what Joey said. I cannot find this line in online substitles.

Comment: It's not meant to be heard but one assumes it's a smutty suggestion.

Comment: Jill is a pornstar, so it surely has a connection with that and sex. As PaulieD said, it surely is smutty / naughty

Comment: @Vishwa - no, she's not a porn star. She was, at the time, a model for the world's most famous lingerie brand. She was a fashion model.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

From a [transcript of The One with the Blackout](http://friends.tktv.net/Episodes1/summaries/7.html)

> CHAN: I'm trppd... in an ATM vstbl... wth JLL GDCR.
>
> JOEY: [to everyone] Oh my God! He's trapped in an ATM vestibule with Jill Goodacre! [on phone] Chandler, listen. [says something intentionally garbled]
>
> CHAN: Yeah, like that thought never entered my mind.

So I agree with @Paulie_D it's almost certainly not meant to be heard and is just something smutty.

Some people do speculate that if you listen closely, you can hear:

> "See if you can tell what kind of underwear she wears"

[Source: Quora](https://www.quora.com/What-does-Joey-say-in-reply-to-Chandler-when-hes-stuck-in-an-ATM-vestibule-with-Jill-Goodacre)

Comment: I'm sure it couldn't be *"See if you can tell what kind of underwear she wears"*, It'd be more related to see her naughty parts or try to do some nasty with her or similar

Comment: @vishwa why would it have to be? I see no reason why that persons suggestion couldn't be right

Comment: @Vishwa! Calm down!